# Eclipse with Remote Unit Tests

Tags: linux, eclipse, ant

I'm working on a Mac.  My dev server is linux.  My directory is mounted over SSH using FUSE.  How can I execute my ant script on the remote server within Eclipse?  Right now I'm just switching to a terminal and running ant manually.

Please, no suggestions that I run the tests locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Eclipse has any built in support for running ant-scripts remotely (that is, after all, not a very common use case). The alternative is to run the ant-script using ssh as an external program. You won't get the ant builder's settings, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: I'll try this - thanks.  I was hoping for something that would work under windows too, for the other folks on the team.  Any ideas?

Comment: There are a number of ssh-clients for windows which should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, have you checked out the [Target Management plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/)?